# How do I create a PPA for private use only, not for sharing through the community.?

Tags: ppa, repository

I'm trying to learn about repositories and source version controls at the same time. It's not brain surgery, but, since I'm a boon, I feel like I'm trying to rum a 5K before I've started to crawl.

I am the admin on our systems. They are running Ubuntu 18.04 (x86_64) on HP Z1 G1 Xeon 5350 Quad Core machines. I need to find out if users can create custom PPA's that are also somewhat private, not so much protected.

Is the practice of users making there own PPAs allowed? if not, why aren't they? If the behavior is allowed, is it encouraged? Are there any resources online that have been made accessible to the general public?

Comment: PPAs are intended for sharing. You can have a private repository, but it won't be a PPA.

Comment: Repository details can be read at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (which include a PPA section too)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge that isn't the purpose of PPAs as provided by Canonical/Ubuntu.

> Using a Personal Package Archive (PPA), **you can distribute software**
>   **and updates directly to Ubuntu users**. Create your source package,
>   upload it and Launchpad will build binaries and then host them in your
>   own apt repository.

https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA#keys?action=show&redirect=PPAKeys

There is a NOTE

> Note: **CommercialHosting allow you to have private PPAs**.

ie. you can have private PPAs on your own paid for infrastructure, but the Ubuntu infrastructure which is about sharing and open-source, doesn't provide private PPAs as you I believe are wanting.

Comment: There is no need to upload source to launchpad to  build. If OP wnats a private repo, they can build binaries and share them in a private place.